# Can I release an object which was added to a NSMutableArray or does this affect a crash?

Tags: ios, memory-management, nsmutablearray

I've got one question about the memory management of the `NSMutableArray`. I create an object of my custom class and add this object to a `NSMutableArray`. Is this automatically retained, so that I can release my created object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is automatically retained. You should release your object after adding it to the array (or use **autorelease**)

For example:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[array addObject:[[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease]];

// or

MyClass * obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];

[array addObject:obj];

[obj release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this for example:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *someString = @"Abc";
[array addObject:someString];
[someString release];
NSLog(@"Somestring: %@", [array objectAtIndex:0]);
```